# Android Sqlite can't get records from Listview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, sqliteopenhelper

I am writing a program that saves to DB and then get infos from the DB using SQLiteOpenHelper.
Problem is I insert text from the edit text but I got nothing to show. 
is the problem from the listview? cuz I extend from ArrayAdapter class not from enter code hereCursor adapter? or there is something wrong with my code. Please take a look at my code this is my main Acitvity

```
package com.perfectapps.fasaven.dbnews;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

 import DBHelper.DBContract;
import DBHelper.DBModel;
import newsAdapter.NewsMainMenuAdapter;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button submitNews;
ListView newsListView;
ArrayList<DBModel> dbmodel = new ArrayList<DBModel>();

EditText titleEditText;

TextView tvTitle;
TextView tvInfo;

EditText infoEditText;

DBContract dbContract;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvTitle =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvInfo =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    submitNews = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_news);
    newsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvNews);
    titleEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNews);
    infoEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNewsInfo);

    dbContract = new DBContract(this,null,null,1);


    NewsMainMenuAdapter customeAdapter = new NewsMainMenuAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_news_element,dbmodel);
    newsListView.setAdapter(customeAdapter);
   // printDataBase();
    submitNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DBModel dbModel = new DBModel();
            dbModel.setNewsInfos(infoEditText.getText().toString());
            dbModel.setNewsTitle(titleEditText.getText().toString());
            dbContract.addNews(dbModel);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"saved to DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            titleEditText.setText("");
            infoEditText.setText("");
            //  printDataBase();
        }
    });
}

public void printDataBase(){
   DBModel dbModel = new DBModel();
   String dbToStringTitle = dbContract.readNewsTitle();
     tvTitle.setText(dbToStringTitle);
      titleEditText.setText("");

     String dbToStringInfo =dbContract.readNewsInfo();
     tvInfo.setText(dbToStringInfo);
     infoEditText.setText("");  
}

}
```

This is my custom Adapter

```
   package newsAdapter;
   import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
     import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.TextView;

   import DBHelper.*;
  import com.perfectapps.fasaven.dbnews.*;

   import java.util.ArrayList;


 /**
 * Created by Salem on 22/12/2017.
 */

 public class NewsMainMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
 Context context;
 ArrayList<DBModel> newsData;
   int resource;

  public NewsMainMenuAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<DBModel> newsData) {
    super(context, resource, newsData);
    this.context =context;
    this.newsData = newsData;
    this.resource = resource;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
   public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_news_element,null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.tvInfo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(newsData.get(position).getNewsTitle());
    viewHolder.tvInfo.setText(newsData.get(position).getNewsInfos());


    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return convertView;
}



   //@Nullable
  // @Override
  //  public DBModel getItem(int position) {
  //    return super.getItem(position);
  //}

class ViewHolder{
   TextView tvTitle;
   TextView tvInfo;
 }
}
```

Here is my DB helper

```
 package DBHelper;
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

  /**
  * Created by Salem on 22/12/2017.
 */


 public class DBContract extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


  private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
  private static final String DB_NAME = "newsDB.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "news";
 public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_ID";
 public static final String COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE = "newstitle";
 public static final String COLUMN_NEWS_IMAGE = "newsimage";
 public static final String COLUMN_NEWS_INFO= "newsinfo";

    public DBContract(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
     super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION);
     }

  @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + " ("
            +COLUMN_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            +COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE+ " TEXT ,"
            +COLUMN_NEWS_INFO+ " TEXT );";
    db.execSQL(query);

   }

  @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME );
    onCreate(db);

  }
   public void addNews(DBModel dbModel){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE, dbModel.getNewsTitle());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NEWS_INFO, dbModel.getNewsInfos());
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
   }


    public String readNewsTitle(){
      String readNews = "";

      SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

      String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME +" where 1";
      Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
      while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
          if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE))!=null);
           {
            readNews += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE));
            readNews +="\n";
          }
        cursor.moveToNext();
       }


    sqLiteDatabase.close();



    return readNews;
}

   public  String readNewsInfo(){
    String readNewsInfo="";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_NEWS_INFO+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME ;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NEWS_INFO))!=null);
        {
            readNewsInfo += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NEWS_INFO));
            readNewsInfo +="\n";
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }


    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return readNewsInfo;

}

}
```

There is one 4th class that has setters and getters named DBModel
 and got XML for main activity which has listview.. but it when I input from edit text it doesn't show there

Comment: I am commenting printDataBase();
Cause no need to print while there is listview

Comment: After adding to DB read the data from db set to arraylist and notify the adapter

Comment: Isn't what I've done is doing this? I am sorry but more details @Raghavendra

Comment: You have initialised customeAdapter with empty ArrayList. You haven't added any data to that list and u haven't notify the adapter regarding the changes to the list.

Comment: Infact you haven't set any data to the arraylist. So, after addition of data read from DB set to Arraylist and notify the adapter regarding data change

Comment: ohh thank you so much, I really forgot to do dbmodel.add(dbModel)

Comment: If you restart the app you won't have that data.. so, that's why suggesting u to read from DB

Comment: Sorry I am kinda beginner, how to do so?

Comment: Very simple tutorial check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm